# With what should I replace sun.awt.shell.ShellFolder so I don't get compile warnings?

Tags: java, compiler-warnings, jdk-internal-api

I have a method using `sun.awt.shell.ShellFolder.get("fileChooserComboBoxFolders");` which I want to replace (or suppress the warning if possible). Can I replace it with anything not Sun properietary so it doesn't throw warnings on some possible removals?

--

UPDATE: not sure if the code is needed at all. It's in a legacy code and I was asked to remove all compile warnings. The one particular with the ShellFolder goes the following:

```
new Thread {
  public void run() {
    ShellFolder.get("fileChooserComboBoxFolders");
  }
}.start();
```

--

UPDATE #2 on why it was needed: JFileChooser is still a bit buggy.

Comment: what is the warning? It has no warning for me!

Comment: "warning: sun.awt.shell.ShellFolder is Sun proprietary API and may be removed in a future release"

Answer (score 0):

The only solution to avoid this warning is not to use `sun.awt.shell.ShellFolder.get`

Comment: What can I use instead of it?

Answer (score 0):

You can suppress warnings by using `@SuppressWarnings("all")` before the method you want:

```
new Thread {
    @SuppressWarnings("all")
    public void run() {
        ShellFolder.get("fileChooserComboBoxFolders"); //No warnings.
    }
}.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it fetches the file system root directories (Windows: drive letters) without doing anything with them. This may take a while, hence this might be a speed-up, for the slowness of JFileChooser in older java versions. So **remove**.